# Event Source doesn't represent an information at each client/session

Tags: javascript, python, server-sent-events, aiohttp

I have a python server-side which sends a request using SSE.

Here the example of python code. It sends an 'action-status' and data which JS has to handle (to do):

```py
async def sse_updates(request):
    loop = request.app.loop
    async with sse_response(request) as resp:
        while True:

            # Sending request for queue' token remove when it's been removed on server.
            if request.app['sse_requests']['update_queue_vis_remove']:
                await resp.send("update-remove")
                request.app['sse_requests']['update_queue_vis_remove'] = False

            # Sending request for queue' token adding up when it's been added on server.
            if request.app['sse_requests']['update_queue_vis_append'][0]:
                await resp.send(f"update-append {request.app['sse_requests']['update_queue_vis_append'][1]} {request.app['sse_requests']['update_queue_vis_append'][2]}")
                request.app['sse_requests']['update_queue_vis_append'][0] = False

            # Sending request for redundant token's list rewrite (on client side ofc)
            if request.app['sse_requests']['redundant_tokens_vis'][0]:
                await resp.send('update-redtokens ' + ''.join(token + ' ' for token in request.app['sse_requests']['redundant_tokens_vis'][1]))
                request.app['sse_requests']['redundant_tokens_vis'][0] = False

            await asyncio.sleep(0.1, loop=loop)
    return resp
```

And the JS script which handles a response:

```js
evtSource = new EventSource("http://" + window.location.host + "/update")

evtSource.onmessage = function(e) {
    // Data from server is fetching as "<server-event-name> <data1> <data2> <data3> ..."
    let fetched_data = e.data.split(' ');

    // First option is when a token has been removed from server this event has to be represented on a client-side.
    if(fetched_data[0] === "update-remove")
        displayQueueRemove();

    // The second option is when a token appended on server and also it should be represented to a user
    else if(fetched_data[0] === "update-append")

        // fetched_data[1] - token
        // fetched_data[2] - it's (token's) position
        displayQueueAdd(fetched_data[1], parseInt(fetched_data[2]));

    // The last possible options is that if the web-page will has refreshed a data in redundant_tokens should be rewritten
    else if (fetched_data[0] === "update-redtokens"){

        fetched_data.shift();

        // Creating variables for token' wrapping
        let tag;
        let text;

        // Wrapping tokens and store it into the array.
        for(let i = 0; i < fetched_data.length - 1; i++) {
            tag = document.createElement("div");
            text = document.createTextNode(fetched_data[i]);
            tag.appendChild(text);
            tag.setAttribute("class", "token-field");
            redundant_tokens[i] = tag;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that if I open two or more browser windows (sessions), the only one of them catches a response and represents it. Moreover there were the cases when I send a request from one session, however obtain a response to another one.
Is there an option to fix it using SSE (I mean, I was considering some other methods but I'd like to try with SSE)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is synchronizing the data (`app["sse_requests"]`).
Depending on how you modify the data and who needs to be notified you might need to keep a list of clients (sessions).

For example if all clients need to be notified of all events then keep a `list` (or even better a `set`) of connected clients and create a periodic function (using `create_task`) in which to notify all of them.

If a client needs to only be notified of certain events then you need to identify that client using some sort of key in the `request` object.